# Excel if statement works when true, but outputs "FALSE" rather than a number value when false

Tags: excel, if-statement

I've created a very long "IF statement" in Microsoft Excel, and have one slight issue. The statement opens with the "OR" option, that establishes two possible paths (see below). Every row of data that follows the first path outputs the numeric value expected, but every row of data that follows the second path outputs the character phrase, "FALSE" in the destination cell.

Here is what the monster looks like:

```
=IF(OR(DG386<=3,DG386>3),IF(DG386<=3,IF(DR386<DO386,((DP386-DM386)/DI386)*100,IF(DG386<=3,IF(DR386>=DO386,((DO386-DM386)/DI386)*100)))),IF(DG386>3,(DI386-DM386)/DI386)*100)
```

When I highlight the equation to see how it breaks down, the "logistic test", "value if true", and "value if false" components are indicated as follows:

```
Logistic test: OR(DG386<=3,DG386>3)
Value if true: IF(DG386<=3,IF(DR386<DO386,((DP386-DM386)/DI386)*100,IF(DG386<=3,IF(DR386>=DO386,((DO386-DM386)/DI386)*100))))
Value if false: IF(DG386>3,(DI386-DM386)/DI386)*100
```

I've been very careful trying to get the last part to cooperate, and can't see why it won't. It is error free, and the components of the statement seem to be in proper order to the best of my knowledge. Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Ryan

Comment: The brackets in your "monster" don't match up. Excel gives me errors when I try to enter it. You do need to post the actual formula that you've entered in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

The FALSE response is likely coming since you have nested IF statements but don't define the "Value if False" expression for those.

For example, in your expression, if the "Value if True" condition: IF(DG386<=3,IF(DR386=DO386,((DO386-DM386)/DI386)*100)))) is evaluated such that either of those inner IF statements evaluates to FALSE, your expression will return FALSE.

Also, you may want to double check your starting OR condition -- wouldn't that always be true (<=3 or >3)?  So you're likely never reaching the "Value if false" block.
"

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for replying. I ate something, looked at it again, and did it another way. I've never tried to ask anything on these kind of help boards, and I'll try not to for as long as I can help it, but it is nice to know that people do offer help here. Thanks again for your time and the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Ach, I don't know what I was doing with the "OR" stuff. This worked.

=IF(DG266<=3,IF(DR266=DO266,((DO266-DM266)/DI266)*100)),((DI266-DM266)/DI266)*100)